# SSIS Execute process task and Powershell for expand files

Tags: powershell, ssis, ssis-2016

I am trying to execute an powershell script (the script is unzipping the folders in source path with the same name as the .zip folder)

**powershell script:**

param([string] $sourcepath)
$sourcepath = "F:\Worflow\"

function unzip ($file) {

$dirname = $sourcepath +(Get-Item $file).Basename

New-Item -Force -ItemType directory -Path $dirname

expand-archive -path $file -DestinationPath $dirname -F

}

$zipFiles = Get-LongChildItem -Path $sourcepath  -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like  "*.zip"}

foreach($file in $zipFiles)
   {
   unzip ($file)

```
}
```

**SSIS Executue process task Arguments:**

"-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\MyDataFiles\Unzip.ps1"

**The powershell script works fine when ran in PS instance. But the code is failing from SSIS task with an error :**
Get-LongChildItem : The term 'Get-LongChildItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\MyDataFiles\Unzip.ps1:17 char:13
+ $zipFiles = Get-LongChildItem -Path $sourcepath  -Recurse | Where-Obj ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LongChildItem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Anyhelp would be appreciated. The goal is using powershell to zip and unzip folders or files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are attempting to use a command without first loading the module.

Get-LongChildItem is part of the open source module PSAlphaFS

Try importing the module in your script first.
Of course it needs to be installed too. ;)